# How to avoid black border and glow while blurring bitmap with render script?

Tags: android, bitmap, blur

I am blurring the cropped portion of image. It looks something like this

[image]

So what I am doing is - cropping selected area out of the image and then applying blur to the cropped area and then again adding the bitmap to the bitmap.

My main question is how to avoid the black border and glow while applying blur.

I am also trying to make the selected area disappear from the image, something similar to removing removing blemmish.

Any ideas on how can to achieve this will also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For time being, I manages to solve the problem by first applying blur to a copy of original bitmap and then cutting it out.